# Show that expression is true or false using equations.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question asks to show if the expression

$$(A ∪ B)^c = A^c ∩ (U \setminus (A ∆ B))$$

is true or false using the provided equations.

The equations are:

$X∆Y := (X -Y )∪(Y -X)$

$X - Y = X ∩ Y^c$

as well as [these equations.](http://puu.sh/ktBVl/f41e8d6ec0.png)

I can see that it is true by drawing Venn diagrams, however the question specifically asks to use the equations provided.

I've been stuck on this problem for a few hours and can't seem to come up with anything. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

$U \setminus (A \Delta B) = U \setminus ((A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A))$ by definition of $\Delta$. Therefore the right-hand side is $$A^C \cap (U \setminus ((A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)))$$

Removing all the $\setminus$ signs using $X \setminus Y = X \cap Y^C$, this right-hand side becomes $$A^C \cap (U \cap ((A \cap B^C) \cup (B \cap A^C))^C)$$

By associativity of $\cap$, this is $$A^C \cap U \cap ((A \cap B^C) \cup (B \cap A^C))^C$$

By the intersection-with-universe law, this is $$A^C \cap ((A \cap B^C) \cup (B \cap A^C))^C$$

which is by de Morgan's law $$A^C \cap ((A^C \cup B) \cap (B^C \cup A))$$

By the associativity of $\cap$, this is $$A^C \cap (A^C \cup B) \cap (B^C \cup A)$$

By distributivity of $\cap$ over $\cup$, taking the first term over the third term, this is $$(A^C \cup B) \cap ((A^C \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap A))$$

Since $A^C \cap A = \emptyset$, this is $$(A^C \cup B) \cap (A^C \cap B^C)$$

By distributivity, this is $$(A^C \cap A^C \cap B^C) \cup (B \cap A^C \cap B^C)$$

That last term is the empty set, being the intersection of $B$ with $B^C$ and another set; the first term is $A^C \cap B^C$, which is $(A \cup B)^C$ by de Morgan's law, as required.